# Initializing a struct vector in a struct

Tags: c++, vector, struct

Reading a structured file of temperature readings Example - From pages 369–370 of Programming: Principles and Practices using C++:

> ```
> struct Day {
> vector<double> hour {vector<double>(24,not_a_reading)};
> };
> ```
>
> That is, a Day has 24 hours, each initialized to not_a_reading.
>
> ```
> struct Month { // a month of temperature readings
> int month {not_a_month}; // [0:11] January is 0
> vector<Day> day {32}; // [1:31] one vector of readings per day
> };
> ```
>
> We “waste” day[0] to keep the code simple.
>
> ```
> struct Year { // a year of temperature readings, organized by month
> int year; // positive == A.D.
> vector<Month> month {12}; // [0:11] January is 0
> };
> ```
>
> Each class is basically a simple vector of “parts,” and Month and Year
>   have an identifying member month and year, respectively.

Shouldn't brackets be used instead of curly braces, if the goal is to create a vector of type day/month that has 32/12 members?

Comment: Brackets are used for arrays... a vector is a class that gives the behavior of an array and much more, and being a class, it is declared like a class.

Answer (score 0):

The curly braces lets the compiler know that you want to initialize using an initializer list.

Brackets are used to access vector elements.

Comment: wouldn't vector<Day> day {32}; create a one element vector of type day initialized to 32? I don't understand how that'd work since day doesn't have a constructor.

Comment: Yes.  That should be `vector<Day> day{ vector<Day>(32) };`  My preference would be to write a constructor for each class, though.

Comment: @Nour "wouldn't vector<Day> day {32}; create a one element vector of type day initialized to 32?" No. It calls the constructor where 1st. param. is number of elements and 2nd. is the element init. value (where 2nd has a default constructed default value). Have a look at [**coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/53ac1c5064353266) for demonstration.

Comment: @Scheff In the vector section, brackets are used to define the number of elements (1st argument) and the initial value (2nd element). Curly braces are used to sequentially initialize the elements values individually. On page 370, the author emphasizes:Why didn’t we write
struct Day {
vector<double> hour {24,not_a_reading};
};
That would have been simpler, but unfortunately, we would have gotten a vector
of two elements (24 and –1).

Comment: @Nour You're right. I made a new sample on [**ideone**](https://ideone.com/RGD2qm). It's a bit confusing which constructor is used when. (On VS2013, where I'm working daily, initialization lists are not well supported. Thus, I'm lacking experience a bit...)